# monit - check network Error: syntax error

Tags: monit

No matter what I put in for x, I get the error
**/etc/monit/conf.d/network:1: Error: syntax error 'x'**

This is the full config for /etc/monit/conf.d/network

```
check network x interface enp2s0
    if changed link then alert
    if saturation > 90% then alert
    if download > 90 MB/s then alert
    if total upload > 100 GB in last hour then alert
```

This is what I am using

Monit version 5.3.2
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

ifconfig -a

enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr x:x:x:x:x:x
          inet addr: x.x.x.x  Bcast:x.x.x.x   Mask:255.255.255.248
          inet6 addr: x.x.x.x Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1

Answer (score 0):

Network check is available since Monit 5.11.0. You have to upgrade Monit prior using it.

Comment: Will try, that was from an apt-get install this month